# If Else Java Script HTML

Tags: javascript

The third button is supposed to Bring up a prompt in which you can type in a number from 1-3 and if you type something else it should say that what you typed in is not a number between 1 and 3, but if you type 1/2/3 it should bring up a prompt in which you can type your text, and the text that is under 1/2/3 should change into what you typed.
Instead, when you type in something not from 1 to 3 in the first prompt it still brings up the second one(which it should not), and no matter what you type in the first prompt it will only change the first text.
Sorry if it's just a dumb mistake, i spent hours trying to figure it out.

```
function HI()
{
    var A = prompt("Choose Text(1-3)")
    if(A = 1)
    {
        A=document.getElementById("1");
        var B = prompt("Type Your Text")
        A.innerHTML=B;
    }
    else if(A = 2)
    {
        A=document.getElementById("2");
        var B = prompt("Type Your Text")
        A.innerHTML=B;
    }
    else if(A = 3)
    {
        A=document.getElementById("3");
        var B = prompt("Type Your Text")
        A.innerHTML=B;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("What you typed is not a between 1 and 3")
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: You are not performing a comparison in your if-statements but an assignment. Go and look up JavaScript operators in your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

You need the equality indicator, not the assignment operator. Use `A == 1` or `B == 1` or whatever.

Comment: Knew it was a dumb mistake, mentioned it too

Comment: @RichardNalbandyan Don't worry about it, I've made plenty too :-). We all do, otherwise we aren't developers

Comment: Writing Yoda conditions is a good way to prevent repeating this in the future; place the constant on the left side of the equality and if you inadvertently use an assignment you'll get an error which should be easy to trace.

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard that term before, but I instantly like it :-)

Comment: Be warned, many people don't like it as it reduces readability; personally I have no problems reading Yodas.

Comment: @adamdc78 the force is strong with this one :-) I don't see how it could reduce readability to the point of being disliked, if it helps with debugging, it's a winner